# NSString to NSNumber convert

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I try to convert a string :

```
3033547640189791162
```

with this method :

```
NSNumber * myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[tmpId doubleValue]];
```

and this :

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:tmpId];
[f release];
```

and both of them give me this number :

```
<CFNumber 0x13a2b0 [0x3f54c9f8]>{value = +3033547640189791232.00000000000000000000, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
```

insted of :

```
<CFNumber 0x1b5550 [0x3f54c9f8]>{value = +3033547640189791232, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
```

## Edit

When i try to use :

```
NSString *tmpId = @""3033547640189791162";

long i = [tmpId longLongValue];
```

i is equal to = -1631802438

```
int i = [tmpId intValue];
```

i is equal to = 2147483647

so i lose the original number value

Comment: Try `[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[tmpId longLongValue]];`

Comment: Why aren't you using [NSNumber numberWithInt:] and [NSString intValue:] ? As I understand you expect an integer value without the fraction ... Or do you want to control the number of digits after the dot ?

Comment: I edit my post after i tried what you write

Comment: of course `long i = [foo longLongValue];` is wrong. It says longLongValue and not longValue. A long long value does not fit into a long variable and therefor you get wrong results. Just replace that with `long long i = [foo longLongValue];`

Comment: @Nekto, please post your comment as an answer so we can vote on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moving my comment to answer:*

Try `NSNumber * myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[tmpId longLongValue]];`

Answer (score 5):

If you want your NSNumber to hold an integer value you have to use [`[NSNumber numberWithInt:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[tmpId intValue]];
```

You should also consider to make sure, that your NSString contains a valid integer value:

```
NSScanner* scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tmpId]; 
int isInt; 
if ( [scan scanInt:&isInt] && isInt ) {
    NSLog(@"value is an integer: %i",isInt);
}
```

**But there's a catch:**

`NSScanner` validates the number inside the string as an integer, even though it should not … All ARM processors are 32-bit only, so the maximum range of an `unsigned int` is `0` to `4294967295`.

So using `NSNumberFormatter` is the safest way to get the right value, because it handles finding the right data type for you:

```
NSString *tmpId = @"3033547640189791162";
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *myNumber = [f numberFromString:tmpId];
```